# Determine where a SQL Server database is being hosted? Whether its on a local machine or in the cloud?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, windows

I need some help in C# to determine where a SQL Server database is being hosted, whether its on a local machine or in the cloud. Any code will be helpful.

Comment: What does the connection string tell you?

Comment: `tracert servername` from a command prompt. When you say "on a local machine" do you mean "localhost" or something on the LAN (WAN?)?

Comment: The cloud is just a bunch of "local" machines.

Comment: @scsimon But is sounds way cooler  :)

Comment: Please post the ENTIRE connection string, including the user id and password. Then we can help you figure it out. ... just kidding. Don't do that. But in all reality, there is no possible way we can tell you where your database is hosted w/o being able to see the connection string.  And if you can see it, then the answer will be obvious, as it will tell you the exact address of the database server.

Comment: Unless the connection string has a computer name (or IP) you cannot tell unless somebody tells you were the Server is located.